# StatusBarManager

Tags: android

I would like to use `public static final int DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS` declared inside `StatusBarManager` in my application and below mentioned is an excerpt of code from my app

```
Object object = getSystemService("statusbar");

    Class<?> statusBarManager;
    try {
        statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method[] method = statusBarManager.getMethods();
        Field fld[] = statusBarManager.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fld.length; i++) {
            String s = fld[i].toString();

        }
        Class name = object.getClass();

        Field field = statusBarManager
                .getDeclaredField("DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS");

        android.util.Log.i("MainActivity", "value of::: " + field);

        Method disable = statusBarManager.getMethod("disable",
                new Class[] { int.class });

        disable.setAccessible(true);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        disable.invoke(object,new Integer(262144));

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("MAinActivity::", "No Such Class Found Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("MAinActivity::", " Exception occur");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE"

    />
```

Exception is as under

```
01-01 11:45:59.504: W/System.err(676): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at com.example.stopmms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-01 11:45:59.514: W/System.err(676):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 11:45:59.524: W/System.err(676):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 11:45:59.524: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-01 11:45:59.524: W/System.err(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 11:45:59.524: W/System.err(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 11:45:59.524: W/System.err(676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-01 11:45:59.534: W/System.err(676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-01 11:45:59.534: W/System.err(676):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 11:45:59.534: W/System.err(676): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: StatusBarManagerService: Neither user 10045 nor current process has android.permission.STATUS_BAR.
01-01 11:45:59.544: W/System.err(676):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
01-01 11:45:59.544: W/System.err(676):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
01-01 11:45:59.544: W/System.err(676):  at com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService$Stub$Proxy.disable(IStatusBarService.java:324)
01-01 11:45:59.544: W/System.err(676):  at android.app.StatusBarManager.disable(StatusBarManager.java:91)
01-01 11:45:59.544: W/System.err(676):  ... 17 more
```

It gives me the above mentioned exception

Comment: HI, change the permission to android.permission.STATUS_BAR and check

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />`

However, you can only use this permission in a system app. So, if you want this permission on your application you have to install it as a system app, which only can be done on a rooted device.

Comment: And in a system app you probably can use direct calls to `StatusBarManager` service instead of `reflection API`, I believe it's available in system hidden API.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Felipe and Mixaz answers, you need to sign it in the device with the system signature

```
android:sharedUserId=”android.uid.system”
```